Combine Email addresses based on Cell Value (group addresses associated with a company on one line)
I am trying to concatenate all the email addresses associated with a company on one line.
I tried TEXTJOIN.
I am also open to VBA solutions.





Compnay Name
Billing Account Number
Sales Account Number
Email Address
Output




Blue Bonet
1
1ABC
Reta.Ratke@gmail.com
Reta.Ratke@gmail.com; Darren.Lowe@gmail.com


Blue Bonet
1
1ABC
Darren.Lowe@gmail.com



Disney
2
2ABC
Marc.Ratke@gmaiI.com
Marc.Ratke@gmaiI.com; Alessandro.Cronin@gmail.com; Otho.Metz@gmail.com; Nikolas.Bashirian@gmail.com


Disney
2
2ABC
Alessandro.Cronin@gmail.com



Disney
2
2ABC
Otho.Metz@gmail.com



Disney
2
2ABC
Nikolas.Bashirian@gmail.com



Berkshire
3
3ABC
Kory.Weber@gmail.com
Kory.Weber@gmail.com


Mia's Pizza
4
4ABC
Calista.yost@gmail.com
Calista.yost@gmail.com; Wanda.Langosh@gmail.com; Adela.Strosin@gmail.com


Mia's Pizza
4
4ABC
Wanda.Langosh@gmail.com



Mia's Pizza
4
4ABC
Adela.Strosin@gmail.com



Jerry's Barber Sho
5
5ABC
Dale-Boehm@gmail.co
Dale-Boehm@gmail.co


Tom's Dinner
6
6ABC
Celia.Smitham@gmaiI.com
Celia.Smitham@gmaiI.com; Damaris.Erdman@gmaiI.com; Norwood.O'Hara@gmail.com


Tom's Dinner
6
6ABC
Damaris.Erdman@gmaiI.com



Tom's Dinner
6
6ABC
Norwood.O'Hara@gmail.com



Gilberts
7
7ABC
Kelly.Von@gmail.com
Kelly.Von@gmail.com; Kara.Upton@gmail.com; Einar.Emmerich@gmail.com; Leanne.Lynch@gmail.com


Gilberts
7
7ABC
Kara.Upton@gmail.com



Gilberts
7
7ABC
Einar.Emmerich@gmail.com



Gilberts
7
7ABC
Leanne.Lynch@gmail.com





Here is one way of doing this using MAP()


=MAP(A2:A19,LAMBDA(α,IF(ROW(α)=XMATCH(α,A:A),TEXTJOIN("; ",,FILTER(D:D,A:A=α)),"")))


The above formula will spill down, however if you want to drag down a formula then:
=TEXTJOIN("; ",,FILTER($D$2:$D$19,(A2=$A$2:$A$19)*(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1),""))



Thank you, will test in the morning


Load data into an array, group Email with a Dict object

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, colCell As Collection
    Dim arrData, arrRes, RowCnt As Long
    Const KEY_COL = 2   ' group by `Billing Account Number`
    Const DATA_COL = 4  ' concate Email
    Const DEST_COL = 5  ' output to Col E
    Set colCell = New Collection
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load data into array
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To RowCnt
        sKey = arrData(i, KEY_COL)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "; " & arrData(i, DATA_COL)
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, DATA_COL)
            colCell.Add i
        End If
    Next i
    ' populate output array
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 0)
    arrRes(1, 0) = "Output"
    For i = 1 To objDic.Count
        arrRes(colCell(i), 0) = objDic.items()(i - 1)
    Next
    ' write output to sheet
    Cells(1, DEST_COL).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value = arrRes
End Sub

